# two forms conflict with each other

Tags: php, forms, conflict, require-once

I have placed two forms on one page. Bothe forms work fine separately but when they are placed on one page at the same time they conflict with each other. Here are both forms:

Contact Form:

```
<form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="#targetAnchorPage2">
<table>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["name"])){
?>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" class="error">
 <?php
 require_once("contact_send.php");
 ?>
 </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

<tr><td><label for="name" class="<?=$name_class?>">name:</label></td><td><input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" value="<?=$name?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="email" class="<?=$emailaddress_class?>">email:</label></td><td><input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" value="<?=$emailaddress?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><label id="tworows" for="message" class="<?=$message_class?>">your message:</label></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><textarea  name="message" cols="22" rows="6" value="<?=$message_class?>"></textarea>
 </td></tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><br /><input class="button" type="submit" value="">   
 </td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Subscribe Form:

```
<form name="subscribeform" id="subscribeform" method="post" action="#targetAnchorPage3">
<table>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["name"])){
?>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" class="error">
 <?php
 require_once("subscribe_send.php");
 ?>
 </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

<tr><td><label for="name" class="<?=$name_class?>">name:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" value="<?=$name?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="email" class="<?=$emailaddress_class?>">email:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" value="<?=$emailaddress?>"></td></tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><br /><input class="button" type="submit" value="">   
 </td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

How can this be solved? Is it caused by the "required_once" command?

Comment: If they conflict, then the problem is in the rendered HTML for the forms

Comment: What do you mean by "they conflict with each other"?  Are you getting specific errors?

Comment: What do you mean by 'conflict'?

Comment: Please elaborate on how they conflict.

Comment: Try pasting the interpreted HTML code rather than PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that since you are showing the required files based on the same criteria `isset($_POST['name'])` and since both forms have the `name` field you end up showing the code in both requires regardless of which form is submitted.  You should simply change the form field names on on of the forms such that they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms have the same action attribute, they both point back to the same page (note that the hash is not sent to the server). As they both have a field called `name` and you are checking for that, both actions get executed regardless of which form was sent in.

You can do either:

- use different scripts / form processors (don't post back to the same page)
- use a different check for each form, for example by adding a hidden input that will allow you to distinguish between the forms.

Comment: They do not have the same action attribute. The action for the first form is #targetAnchorPage2 and the action for the second is #targetAnchorPage3. And the hash IS sent to the server.

Comment: @Piontek Media See this simple example with two forms with hashes in the `action` attribute and a `var_dump($_SERVER);`. You can submit either form but the hash is not found (at least not in `$_SERVER`...): http://codepad.viper-7.com/fcvX8p

Comment: @PiontekMedia The hash is strictly client-side.

Comment: Yup I misinterpreted that, my mistake. Sorry, you are correct!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
  formaction="Your_URL"
```

Attribut  in Button